# Subtle Bristling Motion

Tags: harmony

In a book about harmony it talks about creating an effect of bristling motion with regard to arpeggiated notes, what is " bristling motion" and how is it related to arpeggiation?
[image]

Comment: Wouldn’t this question be better suited to a language forum? “Bristling” is not a musical term (although i may use it as an expression mark some time in the future), but rather a description of something being puffed-up, agitated, annoyed, spiky or overflowing.

Comment: Hi Arash, welcome to the site. As @DeanRansevycz says, "bristling" is not a common musical term - it seems like a metaphor that the author of this particular book has chosen. If it's not clear to you what he means in context, maybe it's just poor writing; unfortunately it's even harder for us to guess without seeing the relevant pages of the book...

Comment: Could you perhaps show us the text of the book you are referring to - the whole paragraph or section, in context? (taking a good picture of the page with a smartphone is easy) That would make it much easier to understand how "bristling" is being used there. As has been mentioned,  "bristling"  is not a technical musical term.

Comment: Thanks for replies, I added an image to the question above.Hope it works!

Comment: Looks like the book in question was written or translated by someone with a poor grasp of the English language. The text makes absolutely no sense at all to me beyond the advice that arpeggios should be sequenced with lower velocities, which I don't think think is true in general. I suggest looking for a more serious work on harmony that is not targeted at computer musicians specifically, but for all musicians.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verb: bristle

1. Be in a state of movement or action

It's not a very complex word so I'm not sure why everybody is in such a huff. What the author is describing is pretty simple, as to be expected for a book that seems like it was written for amateur game devs to put music to their projects. What he means is that in order to give a sense of excitement or motion to the song you can arpeggiate your chords very quickly with a low velocity as to not interrupt what ever melody you have going over the top of it. It's an easy means of livening up your piece. It's much more interesting than simply holding the chord for two bars or playing the full chord in the rhythm he is suggesting with the bass staff. Notice the highest note is also played with the bass line.